# Database size remain the same after lots of rows deleted

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

Python Version: 2.7
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
for id in ids:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id = ?", (id,))
    conn.commit()
```

Delete seems to work, but the size of "Database.db" remain the same. 
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't surprising.  Databases are collections of files (or other units of storage).  These files store data on something called a data page.  Data pages contains rows.  And tables are logical constructs with their rows stored on data pages.

When you delete a record from a table, you are changing the data pages that represent that table (perhaps even removing some).  However, you are not changing the *database*, only the data in the *table*.

Comment: then what should I do to reduce the database size?  Because the space is limited and I need to free up some space.

Comment: @J.Joe . . . In SQLite, I believe you use `vacuum`:  https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon has already explained why the database size does not change on disk. In the case of SQLite, you can use the [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command to rebuild the database into minimal space after a large number of deletes.

The official docs are usually pretty dry when explaining these things. More info can be found [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-vacuum/). Some snippets:

> SQLite first copies data within a database file to a temporary
>   database. This operation defragments the database objects, ignores the
>   free spaces, and repacks individual pages.  Then, SQLite copies the
>   content of the temporary database file back to the original database
>   file. The original database file is overwritten.
>
> The VACUUM command does not change the content of the database except
>   the rowid values. If you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, the VACUUM
>   does not change values of that column. However, if you use unaliased
>   rowid, the VACUUM command will reset the rowid values. Besides
>   changing the rowid values, the VACUUM command also builds the index
>   from the scratch.
>
> It is a good practice to perform the VACUUM command periodically,
>   especially when you delete the large table or index.
>
> It is important to note that the VACCUM command requires storage for
>   hold the original file and also the copy.

Answer (score -1):

the size of "Database.db" maybe is not equal to the size of table.